# Нужно ли тире в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Нужно ли тире в следующем предложении?

> У кого-то в сердце любовь(?) у меня же — пустота.

Т. к. далее следует тире, я не знаю, как тут поступить. Ставить два тире? Или же тире перед "пустота" лишнее?

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае тире было бы "факультативным тире" - т.е. допустимой, но совершенно не обязательной заменой для обычной запятой.
Поэтому в данной случае я бы просто порекомендовал не прибегать к постановке тире и поставить запятую:

> У кого-то в сердце любовь, у меня же - пустота.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в этой ситуации правильно говорить не авторское тире, а факультативное

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, да, пожалуй, Вы правы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Мне тоже больше нравится вариант, предложенный в предыдущих ответах:

***У кого-то в сердце любовь, у меня же — пустота.***

Но хотелось бы обозначить следующее.

> **При отсутствии паузы** в месте пропуска члена предложения **тире не ставится**: *Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку* (Ч.); *Из нашей батареи только Солёный пойдёт на барже, мы же со строевой частью* (Ч.); *Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него* (Дост.); *У вора один грех, а у нас с хозяином десять* (Остр.); *…Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие* (Леон.).

См.: [**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#) (справочник Розенталя).

Поэтому считаю, что и такой вариант имеет право на жизнь:

***У кого-то в сердце любовь — у меня же пустота.***

Comment: Красивый ответ! А ведь можно (для обозначения паузы, если она нужна автору) и многоточие поставить. _У кого-то в сердце любовь — у меня же... пустота. У кого-то в сердце любовь — у меня же... Пустота!_ Мне кажется, что именно так возможно _показать_ эмоции.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, Римма, абсолютно согласен. Не понимаю, за что минус поставили в Вашем ответе о двоеточии.

Comment: Простое, но пунктуационно интересное предложение — с возможной постановкой (или не постановкой) двух факультативных тире. Не правда ли? P. S. И я не понимаю. Я так старалась **ничего** не упустить.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю так.

*У кого-то в сердце любовь, у меня же - пустота.*

Вообще рекомендацию о нежелательности двух тире часто неправомерно абсолютизируют, но в вашем примере оно реально работает: два тире в одном предложении воспринималось бы как одно парное, что крайне нежелательно.

В подобных случаях обычно встает вопрос, от какого тире можно избавиться, не нарушая грамматику, орфографию и семантику фразы.
В вашем примере тире перед "пустота" предопределено правилами, оно стоит на месте пропущенного слова ("в сердце"), восстанавливаемого из первой части фразы, без правки самой фразы от этого тире не избавиться.
Поэтому единственный вариант заменить факультативное тире (перед "у меня же") на запятую. Понятно, что тире в этом месте не просто так хочется поставить, оно ставится, если автор хочет подчеркнуть противопоставление двух частей фразы. Но в данном случае такое тире мало что дает в понимании, смысл противопоставления очевиден и без пунктуационного подчеркивания. Так что от этого тире в месте интонационного членения фразы (т.н. периода) вполне можно отказаться в пользу обычной запятой.